# Custom validations in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

Iam using Ext3.3
In my application iam design email field in composite field,So when set vtype:email,its not shows error icon ,its shows only redline in txtfield
And also how to write custom validations in ExtJS like Phone numbers and numaric values

Please help me

when iam using

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
    phone: function (value, field) {
        debugger;
        return value.replace(/[ \-\(\)]/g, '').length == 10;
    },
    phoneText: 'Wrong phone number, please make sure it contains 10 digits',
    phoneMask: /[ \d\-\(\)]/
});
```

its shows an error object does not support this property

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `msgTarget : 'side'` for the field to see the error icon.

See here for a list of vtypes : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?4271-More-VTypes!

Comment: thanq for ur replay,,,yes i have used msgTarget:'side',but in composite field its shows white color total composite field,not showing image(warninig/error image)         Thanks